# Can I run Chrome stable and canary in parallel?

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to keep the two in parallel ? I know you can on windows and osx on ubuntu I get a conflict when trying to install either one if the other is installed.

Comment: Where come from your canary chrome for linux ? I can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 4):

Chrome [Canary builds are not](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Linux) available [for Linux](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs), so there's no way to get them running.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but I would suggest using Chrome for your daily browsing and Chromium latest version in parallel for development.

You can find the latest Chromium builds on the CI: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html

And more detailed information over there: http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2012/11/20/canary-alternative-for-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the development version in a chroot: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Comment: dev channel is not the same as canary